# what is the median of this random variable?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, median

Okay so either I'm integrating wrong or the book is wrong i'm trying to calculate the  median of the given cumulative distribution function of $F(x) = x^2/16$ $for 0\le x \le4$ 
The answer in the book is 2.83

Comment: I do and somehow I end up with $x^4$

Comment: Hint: your 2.83 is actually $2\sqrt2=\sqrt8$.

Comment: And that's where I'm lost when I integrate !

Comment: Good news, there is no need to integrate. But what is the definition of a median, already?

Comment: Oh okay I see what you are saying if I were to list out all the possible values in between the interval then its easier to calculate

Comment: @Bartholomew Please show your calculation of the median

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the median is the unique number $x$ for which $F(x)=1/2$, which gives $x=2\sqrt{2}$, which is approximated by $2.83$.

Comment: Again how did you calculate that?

Comment: "Unique" or not, which is why one rather looks for **a** median.